# Java: how to convert unicode string Emoji to Integer

Tags: java, unicode-string

I received an unicode string to contain Emoji code, example: "U+1F44F" (from Emoji table : http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode).

I want to convert this string to an Integer how can I do that ?

I tried this, but it crashs:

```
int hex = Integer.parseInt(unicodeStr, 16);
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: My guess is that you can drop the leading `U+` and convert the `1F44F` from hex to decimal.

Comment: `int hex = Integer.parseInt(unicodeStr.substring(2), 16);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment of @flakes gives the correct answere. The U+ only indicates that the following codepoint (or hex number) is a Unicode. The value you want to convert into an Integer is the codepoint, so you have to omit the 2 first characters with `.substring(2)`

You wil obtain the following code:

```
int hex = Integer.parseInt(unicodeStr.substring(2), 16);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unicode numbers such "characters," *code points*, upto the 3 byte range, such as U+1F44F.

Java String has a constructor with code points.

```
int[] codepoints = { 0x1F44F };
String s = new String(codepoints, 0, codepoints.length);

public static String fromCodepoints(int... codepoints) {
    return new String(codepoints, 0, codepoints.length);
}

s = fromCodepoints(0x1F44F, 0x102);
```

Java String contains Unicode as an internal array of chars. Every char '(2 bytes) being UTF-16 encoded. For lower ranges a char can be a code point. And U+0102 could be written as `"\u0102"` containing the char `'\u0102'`.

Note that emoji must be representable in the font.

```
Font font = ...
if (!font.canDisplay(0x1F44F)) {
    ...
}
```